# Chainlink Functions: Compilation failed - undeclared identifier

Tags: chainlink

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> contracts/TADIEngine.sol:211:29:
    |
211 |     bytes32 assignedReqID = sendRequest(req, subscriptionId, gasLimit);
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Hi guys I am using the chainlink functions hardhat starter kit. Failing to compile for some reason. `sendRequest` is a function in an imported contract. Link to the full contract:
https://github.com/pyromaus/dhlrequest/blob/main/TADIEngine.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is you need to let the contract know to inherit from `FunctionsClient`

`contract TADIEngine is FunctionsClient{`

Comment: you are a life saver my friend, slipped my mind, have a good day man bless